# How to remove negative numbers from a Seq except the first negative number?

Tags: scala

How to remove all negative numbers from a sequence, except the first negative number. I'm not to sure how to keep the first negative number and then remove the other negative numbers.

```
def negativeNumbers(sequence: Iterable[Int]): Iterable[Int] = {
   sequence.filter(_ > 0)
   return sequence
}

negativeNumbers(Seq(6, 2, -4, 7, 9, 10, -15, 8, -20))
```

after execution I should get Seq(6 , 2 , -4 , 7 , 9 , 10 , 8)

Because -4 is the FIRST negative number which means it doesn't get remove, But the other negative numbers get removed.

Comment: Not sure why you removed the example input and output  In general, including those is a good thing.

Comment: Without a reply the @TheArchetypalPaul's remark, I think the earlier version was better, so I have rolled back. If people make helpful remarks about what would help in a question, please respond to them and/or take appropriate action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` gets you close:

```
scala> val vs = Seq(6, 2, -4, 7, 9, 10, -15, 8, -20)
vs: Seq[Int] = List(6, 2, -4, 7, 9, 10, -15, 8, -20)

scala> val (pos, rest) = vs span (_ >= 0)
pos: Seq[Int] = List(6, 2)
rest: Seq[Int] = List(-4, 7, 9, 10, -15, 8, -20)

scala> (pos :+ rest.head) ++ (rest.tail filter (_ >= 0))
res0: Seq[Int] = List(6, 2, -4, 7, 9, 10, 8)
```

Edit:

```
scala> def f(vs: Iterable[Int]) = {
     | val (pos, rest) = vs span (_ >= 0)
     | (pos ++ rest.headOption) ++ (rest drop 1 filter (_ >= 0))
     | }
f: (vs: Iterable[Int])Iterable[Int]

scala> f(List(1,2,3))
res9: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> f(vs)
res10: Iterable[Int] = List(6, 2, -4, 7, 9, 10, 8)
```

Comment: any ideas on how to get it inside of my function?                                           def negativeNumbers(sequence: Iterable[Int]): Iterable[Int] = {  }

Comment: Assumes there is at least one negative number? (and `:+` isn't defined for Iterable)

Comment: "I'm still new to Scala..." And the assignment you've been given is intended to help you move beyond that (that is, do you really want the answer handed to you on a plate, or do you intend to do some learning along the way?)

Comment: @the Archetypal Paul I like your logic

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
seq.foldLeft(false -> List.empty[Int]) {
  case ((true, ls), neg) if (neg < 0) =>
    true -> ls // after firstFound=true
  case ((false, ls), neg) if (num < 0) =>
    true -> (ls :+ neg)
  case ((firstFound, ls), positive) =>
    first -> (ls :+ positive)
}._2 // get just List from last state
```

Comment: Is that a serious question? Just try the code as implementation/body of the `def`. BTW  you don't need `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Split the list into the leading bit with non-negative elements and the rest (which, if non-empty, must start with a negative number). Remove the other negative numbers from the rest

```
def negativeNumbers(sequence: Iterable[Int]): Iterable[Int] = {
    val (before, after) = sequence.span(_>=0)

    if (after.isEmpty) before else before ++ Iterable(after.head) ++ after.tail.filter(_>=0)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val seq = Seq(6, 2, -4, 7, 9, 10, -15, 8, -20)
val neg = seq.filter{a => a<0}
seq.filter{ b => b>0 || b == neg.headOption.getOrElse(-1)}
```

Comment: "type mismatch;  found   : Int(-1)  required: Boolean"

Comment: That's an idea, but assumes -4 doesn't appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

My way to do it would be to use scanLeft to track whether the first negative number has been found and then collect the results:

```
val s = Seq(6, 2, -4, 7, 9, 10, -15, 8, -20)
s.zip(s.scanLeft(true){
  (b,i) => b && i >= 0
}).collect{
  case (i,b) if b || i >= 0 => i
}
```